# uploading image separately versus inside rich text editor

Tags: usability, editor

In our web application we have List/Details and Edit pages

On the list page we show default image, and some other short information

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb21pR.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

On the edit page, we have a rich text editor and some other fields like title, valid date and etc.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSF5We.png)</sup>

Please note that rich text editor supports image uploading.

Now I have an idea, for keeping editing clear and minimal, to take the first image from rich text editor and show it on the main page. Is this something that is used in practice, or it is better to ask for an separate image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that defaulting the image on the main page to the first image uploaded to the rich text editor is a good idea that will save most users time and effort, *however* they need to be aware that this image will be used on the main page *before* they publish their changes.

I would suggest adding a control below the rich text box which will display the main page image, and a forward / back button to allow them to cycle through all the images they have uploaded. There should also be an option for *None*, and perhaps even an option to upload a new image (if this makes sense for your particular use case).

Answer (score 1):

I have 4 points on this:

1. The view shown should be consistent regardless of whether a user is in 'edit mode' or 'view mode'. This is important because then the user will know exactly what pictures and content is editable and how to edit it.
2. The edit mode should show the page WYSIWYG (What you see is what you get) and so should include pictures if they are part of the post.
3. If it is a 'featured image' that is shown on the main page rather than within the post then there should be a section above the editor that allows the user to update this image.
4. Below the editor should be shown a preview of what the post will look like to ensure it is clear what the updated page will be.

Hopefully this helps you.